# Install Zoom: cannot find package libxcb-xtest0

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, package-management

My OS Linux Mint 18.3, xfce, 64 bit.
Have tried e.g. this:

[image]

Have also tried to install Zoom from application center and also from zoom website. I have also tried the suggested solutions here.
Can anybody give me an idea how to solve the problem? And: I am not a professional linux user, almost a newby...
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

To install zoom, you need to change directory to Downloads folder then use `apt` or `gdebi` instead of `dpkg` :

```
cd ~/Downloads
sudo apt install ./zoom_amd64.deb
```

Edit your sources.list as mentioned [on this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/426534/153195) then you will be able to install `libxcb-xtest0`.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libxcb-xtest0
```

[see the installation guide](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/204206269-Installing-or-updating-Zoom-on-Linux#h_adcc0b66-b2f4-468b-bc7a-12c182f354b7)

Answer (score 0):

As all things Linux, most of the time the 'correct' way of installing something is **not** downloading files/installation scripts/packages from the internet, but actually using the package manager provided by your distro.

This way you get software updates and also you don't risk breaking your OS because some lib was upgraded to an incompatible version, etc.

Luckly for you, Zoom is packaged as a universal app, a [flatpak](https://www.flatpak.org/), and Linux Mint supports flatpaks out-of-the-box!

To install it, you can either go to the "Software Manager" app which is pre-installed in Mint and search for "Zoom", click install, and type your password and you are ready to go!

[image]

Otherwise, if you wish to do this from the terminal, it's quite easy too! Just open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and type:

```
flatpak install flathub us.zoom.Zoom
```

Hope this helps!